# Java Spark create dataframes from nested dynamic json

Tags: java, json, dataframe, apache-spark

I'm trying to create a spark process which takes any json and converts it into dataframes.
If the process gets to a cell with a nested json it should **create a new dataframe** which would have a schema of the nested json and all of its data.
Here's a simple json example :

```
{"id":1,"date":"2020-11-30T17:02:00Z","col_1": { "col_1.1": { "simple_string": "string_value"} } ,"col_2":1,"col_3":2,"col_4":"abc"},
{"id":2,"date":"2020-10-30T17:02:00Z","col_1": { "col_1.1": { "simple_string2": "string_value2"} } ,"col_2":2,"col_3":3,"col_4":"xxx"}
```

This should create 3 dataframes:
first the main dataframe should have 2 rows (id=1, date... id=2, date...)

Then 2 dataframes which would be created from the nested col_1 each would contain a single column and a single row:

1. Column simple_string one row with value string_value
2. Column simple_string2 one row with value simple_string2

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: can you add expected output ?

Comment: Just as I said above, output should be 3 dataframes from the json. dataframe1 should have first level of the json and 2 more dataframes which should contain the nested parts of the json

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be helpful if you could provide an example table of how your data should look.